# AS2 loaded to AS3 mobile project

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have a problem which I hope someone could shed some light on.

I have about 100 AS2 swfs that were created a long time ago... each is a simple 1 screen animation with a few buttons.
I need to build an AS3 android application using those swfs. So I opened an air android project and imported the swfs with simple loaders.

When I run the application in Flash CS6 it works fine and the AS2 swfs are fully functional, but when I deploy the app to a tablet the AS2 swfs do not work correctly... the buttons are not clickable and the animation is running in loops ignoring the `stop()` function and every other code in the swf.

I figured that the code stored in those swfs cannot be read by the tablet and there for it's not working...
I am realy trying to avoid rebuilding those swfs in AS3 because it will take me about a month!

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Or does anybody know a specific reason for the problem so I can try to find a solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you not embed the SWFs into your application?

Comment: Even if i can (but i really prefer not to) how would it make any difference? The problem occurs only on tablet... works just fine on pc.